# How to fix "port 80 already in use" error in Azure App Service

Tags: linux, azure, deployment, azure-web-apps

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot Rest Api (gradle) to an Azure app service. There is an executable jar in the /home/site/wwwroot folder and a startup script. When I execute this script, the spring api starts but throws the following error: "The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured."

I can't run the app on another port because the Azure App Service only allows inbound HTTP traffic on port 80 and 443 for SSL. I tried killing the process that is running on port 80 but that kills my ssh terminal (which is rather weird).

The netstat -tulpn command shows following output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers) Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.11:35167 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN - 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:8005 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 212/java 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:2222 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 115/sshd 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 212/java 
udp 0 0 127.0.0.11:60062 0.0.0.0:* -
```

Is there a solution to 'clear' the proces running on port 80 and actually run my Spring application on it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you been able to find a solution for this? running into the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I switched to a windows server to host the application and it worked perfectly.